# Escape backslash in a Kendo Template

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, escaping, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-template

How do I escape backslash (\) in a Kendo template? This won't work:

```
 column.Bound(c => c.Username).ClientTemplate("#= Domain #\\#= Username #");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 4 backslashes, but there must be a non-# character afterwards. I would use a space...

```
.ClientTemplate("#= Domain # \\\\ #= Username #")
```

... or an invisible random HTML element...

```
.ClientTemplate("#= Domain #\\\\<span style='display:none'></span>#= Username #")
```

... or an HTML-encoded null character:

```
.ClientTemplate("#= Domain #\\\\&#0;#= Username #")
```

In case the users will need to copy-paste those, test how each option behaves to prevent inconveniences.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I used two spans side by side, like this: `.ClientTemplate("<span>#=Domain#</span>\\\\<span>#=Username#</span>")`.